# Python - Trying to get hrefs into a useable list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

i'am working whit libary BeautifulSoup in Python (noobie) and iam trying to get the href's elements into a list of strings that i can save and work whit. But i only can get one in the list out of the for loop. Can sombody help? I dont say no to explanations :)

```
a_counter = 0
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_="MuiGrid-root", href=True):
        lst = [range(a_counter)]
        lst[0] = link.get('href')
        print(lst)
        a_counter += 1 #not in use becaouse lst[a_counter] = link.get('href') out of range error.
```

What i tried is to get some random elements in to the list, that the error not apear, but it not seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks --- An url of website or some html or soup would be cool

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overwriting the same element in your list, therefore only getting one url.
Instead of doing this : `lst[0] = link.get('href')` you can use `lst.append(link.get('href'))` to append a link to your list.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your question is not that clear and should be improved, this is only one example how to create a list of urls.

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<a href="#" class="MuiGrid-root">#</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="MuiGrid-root">google</a>
<a href="https://www.ebay.com" class="MuiGrid-root">ebay</a>
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="MuiGrid-root">stackoverflow</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

urlList=[]

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    url = link.get('href')
    if len(url) > 1 and url not in urlList: 
        urlList.append(url)
urlList
```

**Output**

```
['https://www.google.com',
 'https://www.ebay.com',
 'https://www.stackoverflow.com']
```